# Convert country code ISO alpha-3 to ISO alpha-2

Tags: android

How can get the country code ISO alpha-2 given an ISO alpha-3?

"DEU" -> "DE"

"FRA" -> "FR"

"PRY" -> "PY"

On Locale I could just find the other way around from 2 to 3